# Framework of x-y plane

Tags: plotting

I have a plot in mathematica as:

```
data = Table[ 2/(-1 + 1/
 2 (1 - x^2 - y^2 + Sqrt[4 y^2 + (-1 + x^2 + y^2)^2]) + (x^2 +  y^2 + 1/2 (-1 + x^2 + y^2 - Sqrt[4 y^2 + (-1 + x^2 + y^2)^2]))^2), {x, .01, 1.5, 
0.01}, {y, .01, .3, 0.01}];
ListPointPlot3D[data]
```

which results in:
[image]

Is there any way to remove boxed line but remain framework of x-y plane .

Comment: You can try `Boxed->False`